# U-SQL-- Read latest modified file from a folder

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-data-lake, u-sql, azure-data-factory

How can we read latest modified file from two different folders in U-SQL ??
NOTE: There will be many files in folder.But we want only latest file(single file)

first folder : E:\mysystem\dailyfiles\daily
second folder : E:\mysystem\weeklyfiles\weekly

DECLARE @file1 string = "dailyfiles/daily/LATESTMODIFIEDFILENAME.csv";
DECLARE @file2 string = "weeklyfiles/weekly/LATESTMODIFIEDFILENAME.csv";

DECLARE @out string = "/output/result.csv";

@data =
    EXTRACT col1 string,
            col2 string,
            col3 string,
            col4 string
    FROM @file1,@file2
    USING Extractors.Csv();

Comment: what's wrong with the provided answer? please mark as accepted

Comment: unable to get latest modified file .. throwing error at DateModified = FILE.MODIFIED(),

Answer (score 1):

So I guess you want from two different folders with many files (and I suppose files have the same format) to take a file that was modified recently (latest modified file). You should use file function and virtual columns for dynamic path

```
@allData =
    EXTRACT col1 string,
            col2 string,
            col3 string,
            DateModified = FILE.MODIFIED(),
            folder1 string, //virtualcolumn
            folder2 string //virtualcolumn
    FROM "mysystem/{folder1}/{folder2}/{*}.csv"
    USING Extractors.Csv();


OUTPUT
(
    SELECT col1,
           col2,
           col3
    FROM @allData AS a
         SEMIJOIN
         (
         SELECT MAX(DateModified) AS MaxFileDate
         FROM @allData
         WHERE (folder1 == "dailyfiles" AND folder2 == "daily") OR (folder1 == "weeklyfiles" AND folder2 == "weekly")
         GROUP BY DateModified
ORDER BY DateModified DESC
FETCH 1 ROWS
         ) AS b
         ON a.DateModified == b.MaxFileDate
    WHERE (folder1 == "dailyfiles" AND folder2 == "daily") OR (folder1 == "weeklyfiles" AND folder2 == "weekly")
)
```